# Differential of a multi-variable map

Tags: differential-geometry

This is something that I find is always a bit vague in differential geometry and would be very glad if someone could give me a definite rule.

Here is a prototype example of what I want to compute. Let $A,B,C,D$ some smooth manifolds and
$$
f:A\to B\\
g:A\to C\\
h:B\times C\to D
$$
now we can construct a map $F:A\to D$ in the following way:
$$
A\ni p\mapsto F(p)=h(f(A),g(A))\in D
$$
My question is how to express the differential $D_pF$ in terms of $Df$, $Dg$ and $Dh$? I would like to see something like the chain rule $D_p(f\circ g)=D_g(p)f.D_pg$ but don't know how to do this for multi-variable functions like $h$ in the above example.

### Edit

Thanks to AlexR and martini this question has been answered:
$$
D_pF.X_p = D_{f(p),g(p)}h.(D_pf.X_p,D_pg.X_p)
$$
There is a follow-up question ["Differential on a product space as sum of differentials"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869913/differential-on-a-product-space-as-sum-of-differentials) on how to rewrite this expression a sum.

Comment: Note that $D_{f(p), g(p)} h$ lives on $T_{B\times C}$. Try to find $D_p \tilde f$ for
$$\tilde f: A\to B\times C, a \mapsto (f(a), g(a))$$
Then $F = h\circ \tilde f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F$ can be written as 
$$ F = h \circ (f \times g) \circ \Delta_A $$
where $f \times g \colon A \times A \to B \times C$ is the map $(f\times g)(a,a') = \bigl(f(a), g(a')\bigr)$, with differential 
$$ D_{(a,a')}(f\times g) = D_af \times D_{a'}g $$
(using the identification $T(B \times C) \cong TB \times TC$ of the tangent bundles, induced by the differentials of the projections. $\Delta_A$ is the diagonal embedding $A \ni a \mapsto (a,a) \in A^2$, which has $\Delta_{TA}$ as its differential (that can again be seen using the coordinate projections). Now, by the chain rule 
$$ DF = Dh \circ (Df \times Dg) \circ \Delta_{TA} $$
That is for $(p,X) \in TA$, we have 
$$ D_pF(X) = Dh_{f(p),g(p)}\bigl(D_pf(X),D_pg(X)\bigr)$$

Comment: Thank, it was very useful to know that $\Delta_A$ has to be used, as well as that $D\Delta_A=\Delta_{TA}$.

Comment: Just for other people who look for the proof of the latter:
$D_a\Delta_A(X_a)=\left.d/dt\right|_{t=0}\Delta_A(\gamma(t))=\left.d/dt\right|_{t=0}(\gamma(t),\gamma(t))=(X_a,X_a)=(\Delta_{TA}X)_a$
where $\gamma(t)$ a path such that $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\dot\gamma(0)=X_a$.